# Windows workflow error handling

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

In side the WF, I want to move into upper activities based on the error code receive at catch activity. 
What is the most suitable way to fix this matter?

Answer (score 0):

Use the TryCatch activity. You just need to determine whether you should rethrow in the catch. It is basically the same structured error handling as in C# and VB.Net.

Comment: thx for the answer,
But what I want to do is, once I get the error code I want to move into upper activity (that the sequence already passed) and moving downwards again.
This is actually possible with using FlowChartActivity activity. But I am looking for another solution.